# WhatsApp opt-out on Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: 8.1, whatsapp

Having switched back to my Lumia 735, I went looking for the opt-out for sharing in WhatsApp, but the option isn't even there.

Does WhatsApp remember that I opted out on my Windows 10 phone? Or do I need to go looking somewhere else?